# How to get the geocode of a specific location by tapping on the map UWP C#

Tags: event-handling, maps, win-universal-app, pushpin, uwp-maps

I went through lot of tutorials which states how to add a mapicon a pushpin on to a map, but all of them require me to hard code the latitude and the longitude or give the address in a text form.

But what i want is to get the geocode (lat and lon values) of any place when and where the user double tap on the map. 
Adding a pushpin there is required too. 
i am not using bing maps api, using services.maps, Devices.geolocation, map control and other uwp map functionalities only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to handle is the `MapTapped` of the MapControl event to get the geolocation of the place where the pointer is tapped. Something like this would do:

```
private void MyMap_MapTapped(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapInputEventArgs args)
{
    var tappedGeoPosition = args.Location.Position;
    //Do something
}
```

Check out these official [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/MapControl/cs/Scenario1.xaml.cs#L53-L58) on GitHub